# why unable to upload file twice use filepond component？

Tags: filepond

first open poup modal upload files is work!but completed first upload process,second time open popup model,and select files, click uploadfiles pond.getFiles() is empty.so not process upload file,
why?how to solve this problem

```js
  let pond;
  //open popup modal window select files
   function importpic() {
     $('#importModal').modal('toggle');
     $('#label').val('');
     $('#description').val('');
     const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
     pond = FilePond.create(inputElement);
   }
  //execute upload files
   function uploadfiles() {
     if (pond) {
       var v = $('#uploadfiles-form').valid();
       var files = pond.getFiles();
       console.log(files, v);
       if (v && files.length > 0) {
         pond.processFiles().then(() => {
           $('#importModal').modal('toggle');
           reload();
           pond.removeFiles();
         });
       }
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I try

```js
   function configFilePond() {
      FilePond.registerPlugin(
        FilePondPluginImagePreview,
        FilePondPluginImageExifOrientation,
        FilePondPluginFileValidateSize
      );
      FilePond.setOptions({
        instantUpload:false,
        server: {
          timeout: 7000,
          process: {
            url: '/FaceLibs/UploadFiles',
            method: 'POST',
            ondata: (formData) => {
              formData.append('label', $('#label').val());
              formData.append('description', $('#description').val());
              return formData;
            }
          },
          revert: '/FaceLibs/Revert',
        },

      })
   }
   configFilePond();
    //let pond;
    const inputElement = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
    const pond = FilePond.create(inputElement);
function importpic() {
      $('#importModal').modal('toggle');
      $('#label').val('');
      $('#description').val('');
   }

    function uploadfiles() {
      if (pond) {
        var v = $('#uploadfiles-form').valid();
        var files = pond.getFiles();
        console.log(files, v);
        if (v && files.length > 0) {
          pond.processFiles().then(() => {
            $('#importModal').modal('toggle');
            reload();
            pond.removeFiles();
          });
        }
      }
    }
```

it is fine work